# Connecting to Teradata on mac via Python ODBC

Tags: python, macos, teradata, pyodbc

I have successfully gone through the process of installing pyodbc for Python 2.7, however when I run the following code:

```
cnx = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=<DBCNAME>;DATABASE=<DB>;UID=%s;PWD=%s" % (username, password), autocommit=True, ANSI=True)
```

I get the following error:

> pyodbc.Error: ('00000', '[00000] [iODBC][Driver
>   Manager]dlopen(/Library/Application
>   Support/teradata/client/ODBC/lib/tdata.dylib, 6): Library not loaded:
>   libtdparse.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Library/Application
>   Support/teradata/client/ODBC/lib/tdata.dylib\n  Reason: unsafe use of
>   relative (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Note: this is a different error than what appears in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655162/connect-python-to-teradata-in-mac-with-pyodbc).
I am on OS X El Capitan 10.13, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the System Integrity Protection for OS X El Capitan. After that was removed the error disappeared and everything is working fine. To disable SIP follow the directions at the bottom here: http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html