# Connecting to Teradata with pyodbc on OS X

Tags: teradata, pyodbc, unixodbc

I am new to Mac and having issues trying to get pyodbc to work. I have installed:

- Teradata ODBC driver from https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/teradata-odbc-driver-for-mac-os-x
- unixodbc via brew
- pyodbc via pip install

when I try to create a connection using the following connection string:

`pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCName=XXX;DATABASE=XXX;Authentication=TD2;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX')`

I get this error:

Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Teradata' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I have no idea where to go from here. Also, I am not sure if it is relevant but I am using virtualenvwrapper to create my python environment.

I see this similar question (return error is different). [Connect Python to Teradata in mac with pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655162/connect-python-to-teradata-in-mac-with-pyodbc)
and ran the export statements but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Did you follow the instructions found at http://developer.teradata.com/blog/odbcteam/2016/02/python-with-teradata-odbc

Comment: Those instructions are specific to UNIX

Answer (score 1):

I've been encounter this same problem. I took the actions below and the problem was solved (not sure which action really solve the problem, though).

- Re-configure the pyodbc package.

  When installing pyodbc via Git, change the setup.py as follow

  ```
  elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
  # OS/X now ships with iODBC.
  settings['libraries'].append('iodbc')
  settings['libraries'].append('odbc')
  ```
- Setting the environment variables for odbc.ini and library

  Check the odbc directory via

  ```
  sudo find / -name odbc*.ini 2>/dev/null
  ```

  Then set the environment variables as (depending on your directory for odbc)

  ```
  export ODBCINI=/Library/Application\ Support/teradata/client/15.10/odbc/odbc.ini
  export ODBCSYSINI=/Library/Application\ Support/teradata/client/15.10/odbc
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Application\ Support/teradata/client/15.10/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Application\ Support/teradata/client/15.10/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  ```